# How to check for type in loop?

Tags: c#

I know how to check a type of a field directly.
But how could I implement something like this

```
    private bool checkJumpObstacle(Type type)
    {
        foreach (GameObject3D go in GameItems)
        {
            if (go is type) // won't accept 'type'
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

For type, I'd like to pass `Car`, `House` or `Human` as a parameter (those are all classes).
But this kind of code doesn't work.

Answer (score 16):

EDIT: It's actually even easier using [`Type.IsInstanceOfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype.aspx) if you can't make it a generic method:

```
private bool CheckJumpObstacle(Type type)
{
    return GameItems.Any(x =>type.IsInstanceOfType(x));
}
```

---

It sounds like you probably want [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx)

```
if (go != null && type.IsAssignableFrom(go.GetType());
```

Note that this is assuming you *want* inherited types to match.

Also, if at all possible, use generics instead. Aside from anything else, that would make the method really simple:

```
private bool CheckJumpObstacle<T>()
{
    return GameItems.OfType<T>().Any();
}
```

Even without that, you can still use LINQ to make it easier:

```
private bool CheckJumpObstacle(Type type)
{
    return GameItems.Any(x => x != null && type.IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType()));
}
```

Obviously if you don't expect any null values, you can get rid of the nullity check.

Comment: Jon ,What about this ? `if (type.GetType() == go.GetType().BaseType )`

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No, that would only work for direct subclasses. If the point is to be equivalent to `is`, this is the code to use.

Comment: Hey Jon, how can I check with LINQ, if the specific type is on the list AND its overall count in the list?

Comment: @LuziusL  `GameItems.Where(x =>type.IsInstanceOfType(x)).Count()`

Comment: @LuziusL: `GameItems.Count(x =>type.IsInstanceOfType(x))` - see my edited code; both `Count` and `Any` have overloads taking a predicate.